# Implementation of binom.test in R. How it has done?

Tags: r, implementation

Do you know how is implemented binom.test in R? It use a beta function?
I am wondering but don't know where to find it.

Comment: All the code is available and in the case it appears if you simple type the name of the function at the `">"`-prompt. The downvotes are probably because 4 other people (now 5 other people) saw this as an indication that you had made little effort. (The author of a question that the poster regrets can be deleted if they have no answers with an upvote.)

Answer (score 0):

If you type `binom.test` at the R prompt, you can examine the code. See also `?dbinom` or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test